# Implementing top and bottom horizontal scrollbar for an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scrollbar, securityexception

I am implementing top and bottom horizontal scrollbar for an `iframe` .I am using an external site url to be displayed on the `iframe`.

I created one more `div` 'scrollbar' before main div containig `iframe`.On it's scroll event,I am changing the scroll position of `iframe` and vice verse.

This is my implementation.

If I give any url from the same domain ( something like `localhost:8080/myProject/samplePage.html` ), it works perfectly . But for external urls it doesn't work.

This error coming when I scroll top scrollbar.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a
>   frame with origin. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I am using code :

```
 var frame = document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow;
 scrollbar.onscroll= function() {
                //changing the scroll positions of iframe
                var posLeft = scrollbar.scrollLeft;
                frame.scrollTo(posLeft,frame.document.body.scrollTop);
            };
  frame.onscroll= function() {
                //changing the scroll positions of top scroll
                var posLeft = frame.document.body.scrollLeft;
                scrollbar.scrollLeft = posLeft;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a security measure that prevents cross-side scripting and it is called [the same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Although the W3C is working on a [standard for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), this probably won't help you, because the site in your iframe would have to cooperate with you to implement this, which is the case for most work-arounds for this problem.

One work-around that you could try however is changing the `document.domain` property, so that the domain of the site in your iframe and your site match.